# Erro de compilação em kernel modificado do Linux

Tags: lua, sistema-operacional, kernel

Estou tentando compilar uma versão alterada do kernel linux ([XDPLua](https://github.com/VictorNogueiraRio/linux/tree/xdp_lua_core_version)).

Segui os passos presentes na wiki do Arch (pois uso Manjaro) https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel/Traditional_compilation. No entanto, depois de um bom tempo compilando, recebo o seguinte erro:

```
net/core/dev.c:72:10: fatal error: lua.h: No such file or directory
   72 | #include <lua.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:281: net/core/dev.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:49
```

Aqui estão as coisas que já tentei fazer:

- Tentei seguir os passos do seguinte [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079572/srlua-makefile-error-lua-h-no-such-file-or-directory/20080097)
- Mudei os headers do arquivo dev.c presente na pasta net/core para apontar para o caminho absoluto onde o header lua.h está definido
- Reinstalei outras versões de lua

No entanto nada disso funcionou, alguma dica de como fazer esse kernel compilar ?

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa da lib em C do lua instala ela com `apt-get install liblua5.1-0-dev` E garantir que a lib em C do lua esteja visivel para o sistema operacional `export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/lua5.1` e tente compilar.